# Flatten the result of SQL GROUP BY and create new columns from unique values

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas and python and having some issues on something that I feel might be more straightforward than it feels.

I'm using pandas to create a dataframe off a SQL query. This query contains joins and group bys. The result looks as follows after running `pd.read_sql`:

| id | region | type | question_code | question_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DA | B | FA1 | 1 |
| 1 | DA | B | FA2 | 3 |
| 1 | DA | B | FA3 | 6 |
| 2 | SA | X | FA1 | 2 |
| 2 | SA | X | FA2 | 5 |
| 2 | SA | X | FA3 | 3 |
| 3 | PL | M | FA1 | 2 |
| 3 | PL | M | FA2 | 4 |
| 3 | PL | M | FA3 | 5 |

Every row has some common attributes, like `id`, `region` or `type` (repeated for on every row for every distinct `id`).

What I'm trying to achieve is to "flatten" these rows on their `id` and create new columns from `question_code` with the associated value as the `question_score` as follows:

| id | region | type | FA1 | FA2 | FA3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DA | B | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | SA | X | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | PL | M | 2 | 4 | 5 |

Is this possible to achieve using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add the identifying columns into the **pandas** index
- then `unstack()` the *question_code*
- full code and output below

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id,region,type,question_code,question_score
1,DA,B,FA1,1
1,DA,B,FA2,3
1,DA,B,FA3,6
2,SA,X,FA1,2
2,SA,X,FA2,5
2,SA,X,FA3,3
3,PL,M,FA1,2
3,PL,M,FA2,4
3,PL,M,FA3,5"""))

df.set_index(["id","region","type","question_code"]).unstack("question_code").droplevel(0,1).reset_index()
```

|  | id | region | type | FA1 | FA2 | FA3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | DA | B | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | SA | X | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | PL | M | 2 | 4 | 5 |